# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to create login with web api but when i enter this url `https://localhost:44366/api/login` show me this error :

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[IRI.DataLayer.Context.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'IRI.DataLayer.Context.ApplicationDbContext'.

and then enter the URL `https://localhost:44366/api/login/Authenticate`
show me this error

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44366/api/login/Authenticate
>   HTTP ERROR 404

what's the problem ? how can I solve this problem?

My code =>

LoginController :

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly IApplicationSignInManager _signIn;
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSetting> _options;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginController> _logger;
    public LoginController(IApplicationUserManager userManager
        , IApplicationSignInManager signIn
        , IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSetting> options
        , ILogger<LoginController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _userManager.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(_userManager));
        _options = options;
        _options.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(_options));
        _signIn = signIn;
        _signIn.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(_signIn));
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(_logger));

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.username);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(Messages.IncorrectUsernamePassword);
            }
            if (!user.IsActive)
            {
                return BadRequest(Messages.NotActive);
            }
            if (_options.Value.EnableEmailConfirmation
                && await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
            {
                return BadRequest(Messages.EmailConfirmation);
            }
        }
        var result = await _signIn.PasswordSignInAsync(
                                model.username,
                                model.password,
                                model.rememberme,
                                lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(1, $"{model.username} logged in");
            return Ok(User);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            //TODO Create Function for TowFactor 
        }
        if (result.IsNotAllowed)
        {
            return BadRequest(Messages.NotAllowed);
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(2, $"{model.username} قفل شده‌است.");
            return BadRequest(Messages.IsLocked);
        }
        return BadRequest(Messages.IncorrectUsernamePassword);
    }
}
```

}

Startup :

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddCustomServices();
    }
```

AddCustomServices:

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<IPrincipal>(provider =>
            provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User ?? ClaimsPrincipal.Current);

        services.AddScoped<IApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationSignInManager>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<User>, ApplicationSignInManager>();

        services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUserManager>();
        services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>, ApplicationUserManager>();

        services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserStore, ApplicationUserStore>();
        services.AddScoped<UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationDbContext, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken, RoleClaim>, ApplicationUserStore>();

        return services;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not configured DbContext in your application.

Add IdentityDbContext to your application :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And then register it in ConfigureServices :

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And appSettings.json where ConnectionStrings are defined :

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=Server-Name; Database=DBName; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
}
```